# How to add a loading animation during the calculation in the Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am making a website which performs some calculations and then plots a graph. Now what I want is when the computation is going on, it should show a loading animation and when the calculations are done, that animation should disappear.

P.S. It has nothing to do with page loading so I guess page loader is not an option.

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick=function()
{

  document.getElementById("loader").style.display='flex';  //this is the animation div 

  const permutationGeneration = (arr = []) => {
    let res = []
    const helper = (arr2) => {
      if (arr2.length==arr.length)
      return res.push(arr2)
      for(let e of arr)
      if (!arr2.includes(e))
      helper([...arr2, e])
    };
    helper([])

    delete result;
    return;
  };
    
    var randArray=Array.from({length : size}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000));
   
    timeReq = new Date().getTime();
    permutationGeneration(randArray);
    timeReq = ((new Date().getTime()) - timeReq)/1000;

}
```

This is the code snippet, now when permutation generation is going on, I want a loading animation.
When I click submit button, display changes from 'none' to 'flex'. Now how to change display back to none, when calculation is done & graph is plotted.

Comment: Just add `document.getElementById("loader").style.display='none';`  at the end of the function because your code is not async

Comment: Hey, I myself tried it but it doesn't work. It makes the loader not to display at all.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is with `setTimeout` which sets a timeout before something happens. For example, in this code down here, it loads and gif which is loading gif. After 2-3 seconds, the results go from `display:none` to `display:block;` and vice versa with the gif. It shows for 2 seconds, and after that timeout, it gets a style of `display:none`.

```js
// Listen for submit
document.getElementById('loan-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  // Hide results
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
  
  // Show loader
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';

  setTimeout(calculateResults, 2000);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What you are saying is to set timeout for the function and in that duration show the loader and when the duration is passed, show the result and hide the loader. But in my case I want to show the loader during the function call i.e. when the function execution is in progress. Also the time duration is not fixed that how long function may take. So, an clue now? Thanks for your efforts though.